# AS3 setChildIndex()

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to use setChildIndex() to bring the current movieClip to the front.

I have the following code on the first frame of the TimeLine.

```
setChildIndex(currentMovieClip,numChildren – 1);
```

And am getting the following errors.

Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 1, Line 20  1093: Syntax error.

Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 2', Frame 1, Line 20  1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before 1.

Should I be using stage or something else is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will put the bottom-most object at the top:

```
this.setChildIndex(this.getChildAt(0), (this.numChildren-1));
```

EDIT:

Sorry, my first answer was wrong, here's the link to the documentation.
[http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#setChildIndex()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#setChildIndex%28%29)

Comment: I don't believe 0 is the topmost one. If I do that none of my MovieClips show.

Comment: Sorry, I was mistaken, if the code above doesn't work, it seems like your problem relies on currentMovieClip or even some other part of your code.

Comment: Thanks that got me to where I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

```
setChildIndex(currentMovieClip,numChildren - 1);
```

the `-` you were using was not correct, was another character :)

Answer (score 3):

If you only will put something on top, (guess it must be the same for movieclip as Sprites), you need only use addChild for the target once more and the object moves to the top.

```
addChild(a); //indexorder a
addChild(b); //indexorder ba
addChild(c); //indexorder cba
addChild(a); //indexorder acb
```

Comment: Yep I prefer this approach

Answer (score 0):

you need a container.

```
var container:Sprite;

container.addChildAt(object);
container.serChildIndex(object,num);
```